# How to compare date in table to current date excluding time in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

In controller:

```
$today = date("Y-m-d",  time());
$data['details'] = $this->admin_model->getTodayOrders('dt_manage_orders', $today);
```

In Model:

```
public function getTodayOrders($table, $today)
{
$result=$this->db->select('*')->from($table);
return $this->db->like('Booking_Date', $today, 'before');   
}
```

But it showing some null values

In my table all dates are 2015-09-16 11:12:50, 2015-09-16 12:12:50

But I want in my result date should be in 16/09/2015 like this...
Please help me how to do this in codeigniter

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public function getTodayOrders($table, $today){
    $this->db->select('*')->from($table);
    $this->db->like('Booking_Date', $today, 'after');
    return $this->db->get()->result_array();   
}
```